# what does this bash if statement mean?

Tags: bash

What does the following bash script mean:

`if [ -d "directory name" -a ! -L "directory name" ]; then
  # do something
fi`

I can understand up to here:

> if [ -d "directory name"

but I'm lost after that.  Extra consideration if, in addition to explanation, docs that explain -a ! -L

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-L` operator tests whether its argument is a symbolic link. It can also be written as `-h`.

The `!` is the logical negation operator, and `-a` is logical "and".

So this:

```
if [ -d "directory name" -a ! -L "directory name" ]; then
```

means "if *whatever* is a directory and is not a symbolic link".  (`-d` will return true if the target is a symbolic link to a directory.

The `[` syntax is actually a synonym for the `test` command. Either `man test` or `info test` on your system should show you the documentation. `[` is also a built-in command in bash, so `info bash` will also show you the documentation; search for

```
`test'
```

Comment: + for explaining that -a is logical 'and', in addition, explaining that [ syntax is a synonym for test command.

Answer (score 2):

- `-d` is "directory exists," but you seem to know that.
- `-a` is "logical and."
- `!` is "expression is false"
- `-L` is "file exists and is a symbolic link (same as -h)"

So in english this would read

If "directory name" exists and is a directory **and** "directory name" exists and is **not** a symobolic link, then...

The documentation you want is `man test`.

Comment: *"directory name" exists and is not a symbolic link* -- Not quite, `-L` is false if the argument does not exist.

Comment: @KeithThompson true; I couldn't think of a better way to phrase that :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe the second portion is:

...and (-a) "directory name" is not (!) a symbolic link (-L)

Answer (score 0):

The `-a` is an extension to the POSIX standard version of `test` to serve as a boolean `AND` operator. Its use is discouraged by the [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) itself (see the Application Usage section) in favor of two separate `test` commands using the regular shell `&&` operator.

```
if [ -d "directory name" ] && [ ! -L "directory name" ]; then
    # do something
fi
```

The linked page also defines the `-d`, `!` and `-L` operators:

- -d  *pathname*
  True if pathname resolves to an existing directory entry for a directory. False if pathname cannot be resolved, or if pathname resolves to an existing directory entry for a file that is not a directory.
- !  *expression*
  True if expression is false. False if expression is true.
- -L  *pathname*
  True if pathname resolves to an existing directory entry for a symbolic link. False if pathname cannot be resolved, or if pathname resolves to an existing directory entry for a file that is not a symbolic link. If the final component of pathname is a symbolic link, that symbolic link is not followed.

Answer (score -1):

- `[ -d FILE ]` - True if FILE exists and is a directory.
- `[ -a File]` - True if FILE exists.
- `[ -L FILE ]` - True if FILE exists and is a symbolic link.
- `[ ! EXPR ]` - True if EXPR is false.

Comment: That's not what `-a` means in this statement.